# Package: tcolorbox: how to fix problem: "shellesc.sty not found"

Tags: tcolorbox

When I use package `tcolorbox`, file log:

```
shellesc.sty not found.
```

Thanks for watching!

Comment: Update your TeX distribution, that seems to be easiest way! Apparently you use a newer `tcolorbox` version.

Answer (score 9):

The (relatively) new package [shellesc](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/shellesc) gives a unified interface for different compilers like `latex`, `pdflatex`, `xelatex`, and especially `lualatex` to access system commands. It is part of the [The LaTeX standard tools bundle](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/latex-tools).

The [tcolorbox](http://www.ctan.org/pkg/tcolorbox) package uses `shellesc` since
version `3.93 (2016/06/01)` to be compatible to `lualatex`. Since `shellesc` is a required standard tool, updating the TeX distribution should fix the problem.

Answer (score 7):

I had the same issues with MikTeX in Windows. Using the package manager update the `tools` package will solve the issue. 
[image]