# tikz table shape not correct

Tags: tikz-pgf, tables

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                        minimum width=10em,
                        minimum height=1em,
                        fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
    }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
B1 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
$10^{2^{3^{4}}}$ \& C2 \& C3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

How do I get this table lines in correct shape?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Three alternative solutions for this kind of tables:

First: `TiKZ` as in the original question. 
The problem trying to use `TikZ` as an alternative to `tabular` is that the former doesn't adjust node sizes between them. All nodes keep its real size and if they are `draw`-n lines doesn't adjust. One solution for this problem has been shown in [CarLaTeX answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/386732/1952). It consists in forcing some node size, large enough to encompass all cells contents.

If we prefer not to do it, an alternative solution consists in draw nodes without visible border (`draw=none`) and manually draw borders and fill nodes once the `matrix` is finished. We should do it on the background.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
B1 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5^{6^{7^{8}}}}}}}$ \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
\draw[fill=black!10] ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]TabA1-1-\i.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]TabA1-2-\i.south east);
\end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Second: Using `tabular` with `colortbl`. 
In this case, a new column type has been declared (`array` is needed) with 
command `\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}       \columncolor[gray]{.9}}p{#1}}`. All cells will have a gray background. For header row command `\rowcolor` will fix its background to black. I've also used `\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.6pt}` to avoid the problem mentioned in [Adobe Reader and xcolor within a table breaks the line render](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/53253/adobe-reader-and-xcolor-within-a-table-breaks-the-line-render).

```
\begin{tabular}{|C{10em}|C{10em}|C{10em}|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0}
\color{white}{A1} & \color{white}{A2} & \color{white}{A3} \\
\hline
B1 & $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ & B3\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
```

[image]

Third: Using a `tcbraster` from `tcolorbox`. `tcbraster` are more or less like tabular but their elements are `tcolorboxes`. They have the advantage that its possible to automatically fix equal height for all boxes in the same row. So, we don't have to worry about node sizes or drawing in background. As in `TikZ` is possible to define different styles for columns or rows. With `raster equal height=rows` two compilations are needed to obtain the correct table.

```
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster columns=3, 
    raster equal height=rows, 
    raster width=33em, 
    boxrule=.6pt, 
    raster row skip=-.6pt, 
    raster column skip=-.6pt, 
    sharp corners, 
    colframe=black, 
    colback=black!10, 
    halign=center, 
    valign=bottom, 
    raster row 1/.style={colback=black, colupper=white}]
\tcbitem A1 
\tcbitem A2 
\tcbitem A3 
\tcbitem B1 
\tcbitem $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$
\tcbitem B3 
\end{tcbitemize}
```

[image]

The complete code for all three solutions is:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools,array,colortbl}
\usepackage[most]{tcolorbox}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix, backgrounds}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            %draw=black,
            align=center,
                        text width=10em,
                        %fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
    }
        }

\newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    \columncolor[gray]{.9}}p{#1}}

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
B1 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
};
\begin{scope}[on background layer]
\foreach \i in {1,2,3}
\draw[fill=black!10] ([xshift=\pgflinewidth]TabA1-1-\i.south west) rectangle ([xshift=-\pgflinewidth]TabA1-2-\i.south east);
\end{scope}

\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary: with \texttt{TikZ} drawing cells on background layer}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\setlength\arrayrulewidth{.6pt}
\centering
\begin{tabular}{|C{10em}|C{10em}|C{10em}|}
\hline
\rowcolor[gray]{0}
\color{white}{A1} & \color{white}{A2} & \color{white}{A3} \\
\hline
B1 & $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ & B3\\
\hline 
\end{tabular}
\caption{Glossary: with \texttt{coltbl}}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}

\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tcbitemize}[%
    raster columns=3, 
    raster equal height=rows, 
    raster width=33em, 
    boxrule=.6pt, 
    raster row skip=-.6pt, 
    raster column skip=-.6pt, 
    sharp corners, 
    colframe=black, 
    colback=black!10, 
    halign=center, 
    valign=bottom, 
    raster row 1/.style={colback=black, colupper=white}]
\tcbitem A1 
\tcbitem A2 
\tcbitem A3 
\tcbitem B1 
\tcbitem $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$
\tcbitem B3 
\end{tcbitemize}
\caption{Glossary: with \texttt{tcolorbox}}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

Comment: Thx for the Code! with the third option: So elements of the table I just specify consequtively in each row of code (no ampersand?)? Btw: I have an error compiling your code: fist it says "tcbprocessing.code.tex version 4.10" and then it's complaining "shellesc.sty not found"?!?!

Comment: @Diger   In a tcbraster you just list the elements and they are automatically distributes according the `raster columns` number. It also breaks when there is not enough space for a new row. What I don't know how to do it is to repeat the header of the table. A tcbraster is not a longtable.

Comment: @Diger About the error, do you use an updated system? It seems that something is missing in your system.

Comment: What do you mean by updated system? Is it a miktex problem or a texniccenter problem or do u mean it's a os issue?

Comment: @Diger I mean a "miktex" problem. texniccenter is just a front end to your "latex-system" which is provided by MikTeX (in your case). MikTeX provides frequent updates to itself and packages (visit www.miktex.org). The error you have seems to be due to an outdated `tcolorbox` version.

Comment: OK, I manually added tcolorbox in the package manager but it didn't solve it :-(. Here is the complete error :-/, I dont know what to do...LaTeX Warning: You have requested, on input line 22, version
               `2011/11/10' of package listingsutf8,
               but only version
               `2007/11/11 v1.1 Adding support for UTF-8 to listings (HO)'
               is available.

Comment: (...\tcolorbox\tcblistings.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistings.code.tex' version '4.10'
(...\tcolorbox\tcblistingscore.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcblistingscore.code.tex' version '4.10'
(...\tcolorbox\tcbprocessing.code.tex
Library (tcolorbox): 'tcbprocessing.code.tex' version '4.10'
! LaTeX Error: File `shellesc.sty' not found.
Type X to quit or <RETURN> to proceed,
or enter new name. (Default extension: sty)
Enter file name: 
! Emergency stop.
<read *>

Comment: Try to look at: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/324150/package-tcolorbox-how-to-fix-problem-shellesc-sty-not-found

Comment: OK, I updated it...though I had to update it more than once, because everytime he found new updates even though I already updated!?? (Didn't work until the last update) Now it works...Thx

Comment: Hey Again,
I'm somehow not really sure in figuring out what: \newcolumntype{C}[1]{%
    >{\centering\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}%
    \columncolor[gray]{.9}}p{#1}} exactly does, because it is not used anywhere, right?

Comment: @Diger As it's explained in the answer `C` columns are used in `tabular` solution (second one). It declares tabular cells with centered paragraph contents and gray background.

Answer (score 3):

What about setting the text height of the second row?

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shadings,arrows,decorations.markings,decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{
    table/.style={
        matrix of nodes,
        row sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        column sep=-\pgflinewidth,
        nodes={
            rectangle,
            draw=black,
            align=center,
                        text width=10em,
                        fill=gray!10,
                   },
                        %baseline={([yshift=-0.5ex]current bounding box.center)},
        %minimum height=1.0em,
        %text depth=0.2em,
        %text height=0.8em,
                %text centered,
        nodes in empty cells,
                row 1/.style={nodes={fill=black, text=white, font=\bfseries}},
                row 2/.style={nodes={text height=3.3ex}},
            }
        }


\begin{document}

Hello World...
\begin{table}
\centering
\begin{tikzpicture}
\matrix[table, ampersand replacement=\&] (TabA1)
{
A1 \& A2 \& A3 \\
B1 \& $10^{2^{3^{4^{5}}}}$ \& B3 \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\caption{Glossary}
\label{tabA1}
\end{table}


\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The problem with this is, that I then have a fixed height for ALL tables. I however want the table to be varying in size depending on how much content/text a row has...Defining height for EACH row of EACH table is a bit to much definitionwise...

Comment: So there is no possiblity to have a flushed/justified table without fixing the text height?!?!??

Comment: @Diger Is `tikz` mandatory for you or could you choose a simple `tabular`? See here: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/172523/101651

Comment: Well I liked the style above with the nice black title line and greyish background and it would be unfortunate if I had to change all the tables of my document which are like 50? A bit too much...

Comment: I added minimum width and minimum height to the nodes, but also this does not do what I want...

Comment: @Diger Do you have the height problem in all your table or only in few tables?

Comment: only in a few, because most did work with fixed height. It was just the latest tables were I noticed that I do need variable height :-(. BTW: what does anchor=south mean?

Comment: And what is the difference between: row sep=0mm and row sep= -\pgflinewidth ???

Comment: You could use your `table` style for all the table for which it works and set the options directly for the tables which need the height correction. `anchor=south` is a way to refine the node positioning, see para. 17.5.1 of the `tikz` manual. If you use `row sep=0mm` the cell borders are printed "twice" and seem bigger.

Comment: http://www.texample.net/media/pgf/builds/pgfmanualCVS2012-11-04.pdf is not about anchor south though?!?

Comment: @Diger This is the manual I was referring to: http://ctan.mirror.garr.it/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf